# Calculating multiplication in a finite dimensional algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, sage

Suppose $ L $ be an extension over $ \mathbb{Q} $ of degree $ n $. Let $\{e_{1},e_{2},\dots,e_{n}\} $ be a basis of this extension. Now I know the product $ e_{i}^{2} $ and $ e_{i}e_{j} $ . So we can  determine the product $ a *b $ where $ a,b \in L $. But the calculation will so laborious. Is there any computational tool in sage math/programming/Matlab or something else to calculate this product? You can fix $ n $ like $ 6 $ or $8 $ .

Comment: Sage supports [finite-dimensional algebras](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/algebras/sage/algebras/finite_dimensional_algebras/finite_dimensional_algebra.html#sage.algebras.finite_dimensional_algebras.finite_dimensional_algebra.FiniteDimensionalAlgebra) defined by multiplication tables for the basis elements. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes here is finite dimensional algebra over $\mathbb Q$  and multiplication table are given. So can we determine the product of arbitrary  two elements?

Comment: Yes. See example in the documentation.

Comment: I changed title and tags to match content. Please polish the main text, e.g. the second sentence is incomplete.

Comment: As I understand the question, the OP is considering a finite field extension $L$ of ${\mathbb Q}$ of degree $n$. Thus, there is a primitive element $\alpha\in L$ such that $1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$ is a basis of $L$ over ${\mathbb Q}$ and from that basis somehow the OP wants to compute or find formulas for the products $ab$, for general $a,b\in L$. For the degree $n=8$ that the OP specifically mentions at the end of the post, there are useful comments in the related post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414814/degree-8-cyclic-extension-over-mathbbq by the same OP.